# How do I fix gaps around my lean-to greenhouse?

Tags: repair

Added this to [gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/45561/edit) and was advised to post here.

I got my greenhouse and didn’t account for the sloping away of the wall it was to go against. Meaning a small gap at the bottom becomes 4” at the top.  I can’t push it into the wall as it warps the greenhouse and can’t leave the huge gap.
Is there a way of deal with this?

I was thinking of maybe
 - some type of structure around it then fill with expanding foam then remove the structure.
- some mesh then plaster it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a wood frame with the required taper.

This may also help with sealing to the surface of the wall.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned it’s an old stone wall so it’s not even, very bumpy

Comment: Well you can take a plank and mark the shape of the wall on it and cut to fit - will make the sealing much easier.

Comment: Just realised I never accepted this, a wedge shaped piece of treated wood and some foam filler for the remaining holes did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: @RossDrew glad you have it sorted!