# How do I fix gaps around my lean-to greenhouse?

Tags: walls, gap, slope

I got my greenhouse and didn't account for the sloping away of the wall it was to go against. Meaning a small gap at the bottom becomes 4" at the top.  I can't push it into the wall as it warps the greenhouse and can't leave the huge gap.
Is there a way of deal with this?

I was thinking of maybe

- some type of structure around it then fill with expanding foam then remove the structure.
- some mesh then plaster it.

Comment: Assuming the wall is vertical (which you can check with a plumb line - just a weight hanging from a string) the best way to fix this is to get the base of the greenhouse level. Then it will line up with the wall with no ugly (and draughty) gaps.

Comment: Wall isn’t level, it leans away from the garden at a slight angle

Comment: See this duplicate - already answered : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/164378/97780